# The use of pageNum property in Acrobat Type Library 10.0 JSObject returns RunTime error 438

Tags: javascript, excel, vba, acrobat-sdk

I need to get the page number in order to extract text from that specific page in  a .PDF document. I am using Excel VBA function that makes use of the JSObject from the Acrobat Type Library 10.0

Here is the code snippet and the code hicks up on when I am trying to reference the pageNum property from Doc object. I am trying to avoid the AV Layer and use the PD Layer only, so my macro runs in the background only and doesn't invoke Acrobat Application.

```
Function getTextFromPDF_JS(ByVal strFilename As String) As String

   Dim pdDoc As New AcroPDDoc
   Dim pdfPage As Acrobat.AcroPDPage
   Dim pdfBookmark As Acrobat.AcroPDBookmark

   Dim jso As Object
   Dim BookMarkRoot As Object
   Dim vBookmark As Variant
   Dim objSelection As AcroPDTextSelect
   Dim objHighlight As AcroHiliteList
   Dim currPage As Integer
   Dim strText As String
   Dim BM_flag As Boolean
   Dim count As Integer
   Dim word As Variant


   strText = ""
   If (pdDoc.Open(strFilename)) Then


      Set jso = pdDoc.GetJSObject
      Set BookMarkRoot = jso.BookMarkRoot

      vBookmark = jso.BookMarkRoot.Children


    'Add a function call to see if a particular bookmark exists within the .PDF
    Set pdfBookmark = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDBookmark")

    BM_flag = pdfBookmark.GetByTitle(pdDoc, "Title Page")

If (BM_flag) Then

   For i = 0 To UBound(vBookmark)

        If vBookmark(i).Name = "Title Page" Then

            vBookmark(i).Execute
            jso.pageNum


         Set pdfPage = pdDoc.AcquirePage(pageNum)
         Set objHighlight = New AcroHiliteList
         objHighlight.Add 0, 10000 ' Adjust this up if it's not getting all the text on the page
         Set objSelection = pdfPage.CreatePageHilite(objHighlight)

         If Not objSelection Is Nothing Then
            For tCount = 0 To objSelection.GetNumText - 1
               strText = strText & objSelection.GetText(tCount)
            Next tCount
         End If

         Exit For
         End If
pdDoc.Close




End If


End If

   getTextFromPDF_JS = strText

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

jso.pageNum = 0; set a page number

pageNo = jso.pageNum; get a page number

**edit: 3.3.19**

Mmmh, it seems you have to work with AVDoc in order to get the current actual page via jso.pageNum . Also if you work with AVdoc the Acobat window stay hidden in the background. Example:

```
strFilename = "d:\Test2.pdf"
set avDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.AVDoc")
If (avDoc.Open(strFilename,"")) Then
    Set pdDoc = avDoc.getPDDoc()
    Set jso = pdDoc.GetJSObject
    pageNo = jso.pageNum
    msgbox(pageNo)
end if
```

Comment: I am not able to access the page number with the syntax of pageNo = jso.pageNum in VBA, I get the error 438. Please be more specific.